# This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

I have recently been added to a Github Repo, and for a few days I have been trying to get the apps to launch (no luck), I've solved most of the problems so far, but now I am stuck on these errors as seen by the screenshot I pasted below.

[image]

I am not sure how to fix this or where to begin? I was hoping someone would be able to help me out...

Comment: You're probably best off talking to the owners of the repo as this may already be a solved issue.

Answer (score -1):

Also, you can run `yarn cache clean` to remove the shared cache files.

I hope this can be useful for you.